# In a finite ring every left-sided zero divisor is a right-sided zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A left-sided zero divisor in a ring is a non-zero element $a$ for which there is a a non-zero $b$ such that $a\cdot b = 0$. In a finite ring is it true that we can find a non-zero $c$ such that $c \cdot a = 0$ and vice-versa?

(What I'm thinking to do is constructing the element $c$ somehow, because the ring is finite, but I'm not sure how.)

Comment: One may correctly read the duped question as "Every nonzero element of a finite ring is a unit or two-sided zero divisor."  The proof shows that you can't have something that is a zero divisor only on one side.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no nonzero $c$ such that $ca=0$, then the additive group homomorphism $x \mapsto xa$ is injective (check the kernel), so it is also surjective (by finiteness), so there is $d$ such that $da = 1$.

If $ab=0$, then $dab=0$, so $b=0$.

Comment: But what about left- and right-sided zero-divisors ?

Comment: This shows that if $a$ is not a left zero-divisor, then $a$ is  not a right zero-divisor.